# can I $_POST multiple assoc. arrays

Tags: php, html, sql, associative-array

I am.working on a user input availability database. I order to standardize the information, I want to use more than 1 mulitiple select inputs.

```
    <form method="post" action=''example.php">
Gamerid:<input ="text" name ="gamerid"/></br>

Monday:<select name="monday[]" multiple="multiple">

<option>Select your availability</option>
<option value="4">4pm</option>
<option value="5">5pm</option>
<option value="6">6pm</option>
<option value="7">7pm</option>
<option value="8">8pm</option>
<option value="9">9pm</option>
<option value="10">10pm</option>
<option value="11">11pm</option>
<option value="12">12pm</option>
<option value="1a">1am</option>
</select> </br>

Tuesday:<select name="tuesday[]"multiple="multiple">

<option>Select your availability</option>
<option value="4">4pm</option>
<option value="5">5pm</option>
<option value="6">6pm</option>
<option value="7">7pm</option>
<option value="8">8pm</option>
<option value="9">9pm</option>
<option value="10">10pm</option>
<option value="11">11pm</option>
<option value="12">12pm</option>
<option value="1a">1am</option>
</select> </br>

Wednesday:<select name="wednesday[]" multiple="multiple">

<option>Select your availability</option>
<option value="4">4pm</option>
<option value="5">5pm</option>
<option value="6">6pm</option>
<option value="7">7pm</option>
<option value="8">8pm</option>
<option value="9">9pm</option>
<option value="10">10pm</option>
<option value="11">11pm</option>
<option value="12">12pm</option>
<option value="1a">1am</option>
</select> </br>
```

etc for every day of the week.. so far, I believe my code is correct but POST seems to not appreciate it. Is it even possible..?
The end goal it to serialise the $_POST arrays, into strings, then store them in sql db.

Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: Have yo try echo `serialize($_POST);`

Answer (score 0):

In action page you will get array then by using `implode` you can convert to string then you can insert in to database.

try for this code.

```
    <form method="post">
Tuesday:<select name="tuesday[]"multiple="multiple">

<option>Select your availability</option>
<option value="4">4pm</option>
<option value="5">5pm</option>
<option value="6">6pm</option>
<option value="7">7pm</option>
<option value="8">8pm</option>
<option value="9">9pm</option>
<option value="10">10pm</option>
<option value="11">11pm</option>
<option value="12">12pm</option>
<option value="1a">1am</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$var=$_POST['tuesday'];
echo implode(",",$var);
}
?>
```

Comment: so the code should would to post to action page then.. is it better to use implode or serialize, given that I will need to call on and display the data again

Comment: yes you can...while retrieving you can convert that data into array format using explode methode and you can iterate it....

Comment: okay.. then a need to look for another reason the code is not posting.. atm it is simply return to input page. Have sql errors set, but not even getting that far

Comment: try above code for example ! You'll get multiple values from select & store that while you're fetching the data you can convert into array and display individuals